# What is the command for the symbol used to represent a space?

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

I've occasionally seen a little symbol (like a shortened square bracket turned on it's side) that appears below the baseline and is typically used to represent a space.  How can I get that symbol in LaTeX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's `\textvisiblespace`, have a look at the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

See also the answers to this question: [How to look up a symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol).

Comment: Wow, the Detexify classifier from the answer to the linked question is cool.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can write `\verb*" "`. [Here is a good example.](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~peterseb/tex/samples/verb-command.html)